# JavaScript Hiding a Checkbox after it has been checked

Tags: javascript, java, hide

I am working in a PDF program that allows me to add JavaScript to a checkbox. I am looking to check the box and it adds a time stamp in another textbox and then hides the checkbox. I have figured out the time stamp, but cannot hide the check box. All I need is code for a check box with the name "Check Box1" to be hidden as soon as it is clicked, nothing else.

Comment: Hint: see `setVisible()` method.

Comment: I do not know what that means. I have never worked with Javascript in my life.

Comment: that was for java.

Answer (score 0):

This hides a checkbox on click.

```
<input name="CheckBox1" type="checkbox" onclick="this.style.display='none'" />
```